# How to run web2py project on Apache server?

Tags: python, apache, web2py

I want to develop my project with **web2py**. Before that I make it with **python cherrypy**. and now going to switch to web2py.
But I would like use Apache server instead of WSGI and web2py server!

Could you guide me how do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Into scripts folder(web2py/scripts) are some one-step setup scripts to deploy a web2py environment using apache for:

- Fedora Linux: setup-web2py-fedora.sh
- Ubuntu Linux: setup-web2py-ubuntu.sh

If you have another OS you can check it in order to get a detailed step to step installation guide.

As Calvin said, the deployment recipes are at: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13

Answer (score 1):

A very detailed explanation is provided here - http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#Apache-setup - including the apache2/mod_wsgi configuration files.

Perhaps you can try this out first and ask questions when you run into trouble?

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with **setup-web2py-ubuntu.sh** in version **2.9.5** and prior if trying to run it on **Ubuntu 14.04**.  The main culprit is the fact that Ubuntu 14.04 is using Apache 2.4, which is doing a few things differently from version 2.2.

I've modified the install script so that it will work on Ubuntu 14.04.  There are now only three commands to run to get web2py working on a new server.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ivandigiusto/web2py-install/master/setup-web2py-ubuntu-14.04.sh
chmod +x setup-web2py-ubuntu-14.04.sh
sudo ./setup-web2py-ubuntu-14.04.sh
```

Please note that if you run this script on a server that already has an Apache and web sites configured, it will:

- wipe your current default.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available/
- delete all links in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

To get around that, you may want to manually modify the setup script before running it, or just spin up a new server and try this out on it.